# Error while installing spark

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, installation

I am trying to install spark in windows 8.1 and getting below error.

C:>cd Program Files\spark-1.5.0\bin

C:\Program Files\spark-1.5.0\bin>spark-shell
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Program Files\spark-1.5.0\bin>

and done prerequisites,please refer below commands,

C:\Users\Anbu>java -version
java version "1.8.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_65-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.65-b01, mixed mode)

C:\Users\Anbu>scala -version
Scala code runner version 2.11.8 -- Copyright 2002-2016, LAMP/EPFL
C:\Users\Anbu>

set the system properties also.

so where i missed? why this error coming?
Any one please help me to install spark.

Thanks,
Anbu k

Comment: What did you put in your path ? It seems like you forgot the quotes, so the space in "Program Files" breaks the path.

Comment: as u said C:\Program Files\spark-1.5.0\bin> should be C:\ProgramFiles\spark-1.5.0\bin> ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you downloaded source code package of Spark.

For installations you need built package of Spark. You can download pre-built package of Spark from Sparks's downloads page by choosing a specific package type(as shown in below image). So download pre-built package and check the installation. It should work.[image]

Comment: Hi, as you mentioned i have downloaded  pre-built package of Spark from Sparks's downloads page tgzspark-1.5.0-bin-hadoop2.6.tgz.

Comment: Hi, as you mentioned i have downloaded (C:\Users\Anbu\Downloads\spark-1.5.0-bin-hadoop2.6)   pre-built package of Spark from Sparks's downloads page tgzspark-1.5.0-bin-hadoop2.6.tgz. but still i am getting the same error.C:>cd Program Files\spark-1.5.0\bin

C:\Program Files\spark-1.5.0\bin>spark-shell 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

C:\Program Files\spark-1.5.0\bin>    what i have to do next?

Comment: Are you using latest downloaded package? because when you unzip latest package you should get folder name as `spark-1.5.0-bin-hadoop2.6`. But I'm still seeing `spark-1.5.0` in your command which is older one.

Comment: No i have downloaded what u guided (C:\Users\Anbu\Downloads\spark-1.5.0-bin-hadoop2.6) 
C:\Program Files\Spark\bin>scala -version
Scala code runner version 2.11.8 -- Copyright 2002-2016, LAMP/EPFL

C:\Program Files\Spark\bin>java -version
java version "1.8.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_65-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.65-b01,mixed mode)

C:\Program Files\Spark\bin> spark-shell 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: It seems there is a problem with `spark-shell` script when you spaces in root directory. Can you try running spark-shell from path `C:\Users\Anbu\Downloads\spark-1.5.0-bin-hadoop2.6`. It will work for sure!

Comment: Hi i tried now its showing the below error message    
C:\>cd Users\Anbu\Downloads\spark-1.5.0-bin-hadoop2.6
C:\Users\Anbu\Downloads\spark-1.5.0-bin-hadoop2.6>spark-shell
'spark-shell' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
C:\Users\Anbu\Downloads\spark-1.5.0-bin-hadoop2.6>cd bin
C:\Users\Anbu\Downloads\spark-1.5.0-bin-hadoop2.6\bin>spark-shell
Failed to find Spark assembly JAR.
You need to build Spark before running this program.
C:\Users\Anbu\Downloads\spark-1.5.0-bin-hadoop2.6\bin>  means how to build spark before running this command

Comment: Need to set the hadoop path in environment variables? can u pls come to skype and help me to install my skype id is Anbu Eswaran. because i have  a work in spark